# Cannot create trigger - bad syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to make trigger which update total_money after every insert in transactions table. I cannot create it because of error:
#

> 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '' in line 3

Here is my trigger creation code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER transactions_insert AFTER INSERT ON transactions 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE users SET users.total_money = users.total_money + NEW.Price WHERE users.User_ID = NEW.User_id;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add delimiters it will work, as given below

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER transactions_insert AFTER INSERT ON transactions 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE users SET users.total_money = users.total_money + NEW.Price WHERE users.User_ID = NEW.User_id;
    END;
    //